# Objective-C のプロジェクトをSwiftで書きなおし、同じアプリとして申請したい

Tags: objective-c, swift

現在、 Objective-C で書いてあるプロジェクトがあります。

アプリは既に iTune Store にアップしてありますが、この Objective-C プロジェクトを全面的にSwiftで書きなおしたとい思うのです。

新しい書きなおした Swift プロジェクトは同じアプリとして申請できるのでしょうか？ もしできないのなら、 Swift 移行としてベストな方法とはどんな方法でしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

アプリがSwiftで書かれてるかどうかはストア的には関係ありませんから、Objective-CのアプリをSwiftで書きなおしても同じアプリとして申請できるはずです。

実装言語はSwiftだろうとJavaScriptだろうとActionScriptだろうと、アプリケーションIDが同じであればストア的には同じアプリです。